# how to scrollbar on dynamic chart drilldown in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stack, scrollbar, axis-labels

hi im very confused for the scroll bar x on drilldown column highcharts,i want if bar more than 3 is scroll if less than 3 no have scroll bar depending on filter,i try to explain with this image

[image]

and i try many thing and this my barchart now,the problem if less than 3 labels and labels  have 1 until 3 and i will give you example for the js field same like problem like me "http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xaojun83/"

[image]

and this is the code i add from highcharts stock

[image]

i hope my explain is clear, I need help on how to make it thankyou

Comment: Hi @riyan193, Disabling the `showFull` option should help. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1bdot5p6/ If that doesn't help, please reproduce your current state in jsfiddle.

Comment: hi @ppotaczek thank you for your answer, i try your suggestion its not working from me, can you explain in column chart maybe i can reproduce your state in jsfiddle

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xaojun83/ is an example with column series and drilldown. The scrollbar is hidden on the drill-down level. You can adapt this simple example to show your problem.

Comment: it's the same as my code, but when I select Dieren and it has 3 labels, that's an excess of labels

Comment: So that's why I ask you to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle. I don't know what is happening in your code.

Comment: hi @ppotaczek sorry for late reply this example jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ariyan1919/o6hzbfgm/5/ and i found the another issue if i drillup datalabels is disappear can you help me

Comment: Thanks for the example. The problem is related to using `setExtremes` method in drillup event. Disabling redraw should help. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ejuh9bo/

Comment: hi @ppotaczek thankyou for your answer its work from me, please post the answer and let me give you check green for other to know